# Display message of Saving / Updating between the post and Last Saved At message with Server time in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-interface

I need to know how can we show the saving/ updating message while post to the server. How to tap in the events change that occur. Is there some Jquery available for this. If yes, do send the link.
Also, How to show the Last save at --(Server time) 18:23:12 message on successful save. Please give a Jquery for this also.
Or any other code which will help achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the submit button click on your javascript and post your serialized form using ajax and show a "Saving" indicator or relevant message to the user.

```
@model YourViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Save" />
  <div id="progressBar"></div>
}

$(function(){
  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this=$(this);
    var _form=_this.closest("form");
    //Show a message to user
    $("#progressBar").html("Saving..").fadeIn();
    //Post the form to server
    $.post(_form.attr("action"),_form.serialize(),function(res){
      if(res.Status==="success")
      {        
         $("#progressBar").html("Saved Successfully");
      }
      else
      {
         $("#progressBar").html("Some error !");
      }
    });

  });

});
```

Assuming your Action method returns a JSON structure like this on succesful save

```
{
  "Status":"success"
}
```

If you want to show some other information like Saved time or ID of new record, You can return that in your JSON

```
{
  "Status":"success", "NewRecordID":"123","SavedTime":"03/03/2014 9.30 AM"
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to fetch the server time to pass it to the JSON query